# Download files from FTP location using azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I want to download complete web app root file hosted on azure using  azure logic app through FTP connection.

Will it be possible.Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do it from the web app.

Each **web app** and deployment slot has its own **FTP** username and address. You must enter a new password to use this **FTP** account, which is known in Azure as a deployment credential.

To set up the **FTP** user account, open the web app and browse to Deployment Credentials under the Deployment settings.

Refer this blog for step by step instructions.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/

**For Logic app with FTP , follow the below doc**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp